# Angular sce.trustAsHtml not working

Tags: angularjs

I have this angular controller :

```
 var applicaton = angular.module("appUsed", ['ui.router','ngSanitize'] );
applicaton.controller('gamesController', ['$scope','$http','$sce','$stateParams',function(scope,http,sce,stateParams){     

  http.get('/'+stateParams.category+'/'+stateParams.id)
        .success(function(result){
        scope.Game = result.gameDetails;
        scope.relatedGames = result.relatedGames;
        console.log(scope.Game.title);
        console.log(scope.Game.url);
        scope.gameUrl = sce.trustAsHtml('<iframe allowfullscreen width="80%" height="600px src="'+scope.Game.url+'"></iframe>');

        });    
 }]);
```

and this html :

```
<div class="game_and_description">
<div ng-bind-html="gameUrl"></div>
<h3>    Description</h3>
<p> {{Game.description}}</p>
```

It shows me a white iframe. I searched over the internet and i've done everything right. The modules form angular ng-sanitize is running(called from `<script>` tag) and i have no error. the console log on scopes works like a charm. Don't know where should i look anymore. Please help.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Especially the `iframe` element? Could you copy and paste it to the question?

Comment: <div ng-if="gameUrl" ng-bind-html="gameUrl" class="ng-binding ng-scope"><iframe allowfullscreen="" width="80%" height="600px src=" https:="" play.famobi.com="" nut-rush="" a-dxc93"=""></iframe></div>

Comment: `src` attribute does not make sense, it should be a URL. What value are you expecting / what is the value of `scope.Game.url`?

Comment: something like : https://play.famobi.com/hop-dont-stop/A-DXC93 .the iframe destroy the string. but why? and how do i solve this. I run in the back a node.js server could be this a source problem ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: You should see it now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to give a trust to the URL you are using in the iframe, and compile the html:

```
<div ng-controller="gamesController">
    <div bind-html-compile="gameFrame"></div>
</div>

var myApp = angular
    .module('appUsed',['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('gamesController', ['$scope', '$sce', function (scope, sce) {
        scope.Game = {
            url: 'https://play.famobi.com/hop-dont-stop/A-DXC93'
        };
        scope.gameUrl = sce.trustAsResourceUrl(scope.Game.url);
        scope.gameFrame = sce.trustAsHtml('<iframe allowfullscreen width="80%" height="600px" ng-src="{{gameUrl}}"></iframe>');
}])
   .directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
                }, function (value) {
                    element.html(value && value.toString());
                    var compileScope = scope;
                    if (attrs.bindHtmlScope) {
                        compileScope = scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlScope);
                    }
                    $compile(element.contents())(compileScope);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

See https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile.

The working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/k2e43nvf/

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the directive? i want to understant to please

Comment: In short: the problem with the plain `ng-bind-html` is that, although it does render the html to the given html element, Angular has no idea that there is something inside `gameFrame` that it should handle from Angular point of view. Typically, this means that we need to `$compile()` the input for Angular and this is what the directive does.

Comment: Still doesn't work. o my god something is wrong here.. It is posible to not work because i am using ui-router module, getting the iframe in a template ? and calling the controller there?                                                           `               .state('1', {
                    url:"/category/{category}/game/{id}",
                    views : {
                        "game-view" : {
                        templateUrl: "partials/game_page.html",
                            controller:'gamesController'
                    }}})`

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle / plunker?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot say immediately what is wrong, and I have no time in the next few days to look at this more closely. I would not use any of the HTML binding stuff (`ng-bind-html` or `bind-html-compile`) in your case, because you can achieve the same with a plain directive. I'll check the status in a few days, if you are still looking for a solution.

Comment: i am still looking for a solution. I will announce here if,when i found it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay. Problem solved. It works perfectly with ng-bind-html ( my version.) the problem was that i didn't put the height="600**"** . JESUS so much for so little problem. Anyway THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it like this :

my view :

```
<div ng-bind-html="getDescription()"></div>
```

my controller :

```
$scope.getDescription = function () {
        if ($scope.description != null && $scope.todo.description.length > 0) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.description);
        } else {
            return 'no description.';
        }

    };
```

Comment: I've changed my scope to be a function with condition if exits or not. The scope value exists. and it is called 4 times(i don't know why 4 times but whatever.) but still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: it's probably because you create gameUrl in scope during the success. Try put ng-if="gameUrl" next to the ng-bind-html. Or init scope.gameUrl before your http call.

Comment: the same. I've tried your method. with ng-if and declaring scope outside before http request but the same. And i put a console.log before and after the sce.trustAsHtml and result are before : (empty) (because was declared before http request as scope.gameUrl ='') and after calling sce shows TrustedValueHolderType {}.